# console log with a variable, but not showing list of array

Tags: javascript

I am simply console logging the list of array with the variable temp I defined as showen below. but output only shows the third element on the array. what is this reason for not listing every element?
because when I simply console log arr[i], it shows all 3 elements in the array but not with the vairable temp.

here is my code

```
function largestFour(arr){
 var max = [];
 for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
 var temp = arr[i];
 console.log(temp);

}
largestFour([[4,5,1,3],[13,27,16,5],[10,19,4,9]]);


output 
(4)[10,19,4,9]
```

Comment: your `temp` variable is the last `arr[i]` which is the last element of your list (so the last array). I think that for what you want to, you are missing `{}` enclosing the logic in the for

Answer (score 2):

You must define the `{}` block so the `for` know where it's the begining and end of the block execution.

```js
function largestFour(arr) {
  var max = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var temp = arr[i];
    console.log(temp);
  }
}

largestFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 16, 5],
  [10, 19, 4, 9]
]);
```

**Edited**

What actually happen here in your code

```
function largestFour(arr){
 var max = [];
 for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   var temp = arr[i];
 console.log(temp);

}
```

is the `for` loop when you **don't** define curly braces `{}` or a block execution, he **just** run ( and only ) the next line below the `for` loop.

Comment: how can i do that?.

Comment: Now I did that for you, but when you type your answer, in the top bar you have a snippet button. An editor will popup and you can type your code there

Comment: @Yoarthur, I recommend you to get familiar with typescript because it's a modern trend. I've posted an answer with code written in typescript. It would be so funny and good to your career. :) You can try to execute my code in browser directly. Just copy/paste in browser console, which should work!

Comment: I've already using it on Angular and i can not wait to use it on Vue v3. The questions was made under the javascript tag, so the answer must base upon it?. Don't you think?. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `{}`

Here is the code:

```
function largestFour(arr){
 var max = [];
 for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var temp = arr[i];
  console.log(temp);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to refactor your code and it works

```js
function largestFour(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var temp = arr[i];
    console.log(temp);
  }
}
largestFour([[4,5,1,3], [13,27,16,5], [10,19,4,9]])
```

Comment: you did not refactor the code, you just added the `{}` because that was the only mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

`for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` is equivalent to `for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++);` OR `for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){}`.

Also using `var i` to declare `for` loop initializer make them have the same scope as that of the loop itself i.e the function `largetstFour()`.

So you can use braces `{}`  and  `let` instead of `var` for for loop initializor declaration.

```
function largestFour(arr){
  var max = [];
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    var temp = arr[i];
    console.log(temp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that you didn't know context of **if** statement. **if** statement just wrap only a clause without curly brace `{`. So your code `console.log` was executed only once.

```

```
const largestFour = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach(item => console.log(item))
}

largestFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 16, 5], [10, 19, 4, 9]])
```

```